# phpMyAdmin does not respond to clicks

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, php-7

My phpMyAdmin web-interface is loaded properly, login OK, I can see a standard post-login screen with all database names etc., but when I left-click on anything - nothing works. I can't even logout. Google Chrome console contains the following errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PMA_messages is not defined
at PMA_ajaxShowMessage (functions.js?v=4.9.7:2274:9)
at new_func (error_report.js?v=4.9.7:265:33)
at HTMLAnchorElement.requestHandler (ajax.js?v=4.9.7:305:28)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js?v=4.9.7:2:42571)
at HTMLDocument.$event.dispatch (jquery.event.drag-2.2.js?v=4.9.7:374:19)
at HTMLDocument.v.handle (jquery.min.js?v=4.9.7:2:40572)
```

The server is:

- opensuse 15.1
- Apache 2.4.33
- php 7.2.5
- phpMyAdmin 4.9.7

UPDATE:

Some forums suggest to chmod 777 folder '/var/lib/php/sessions' as a solution to this exact problem. My system (opensuse 15.1) does not have such folder. In my system, the php.ini file variable 'session.save_path' is set to "/var/lib/php7" (i.e. instead of '/var/lib/php/sessions' as in other systems). I tried chmoding it to 777, but with no improvement.

Comment: Check the permissions on **/var/lib/php/sessions**

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but I already tried it. My system does not have such file.
Instead, the php.ini file variable 'session.save_path' is set to "/var/lib/php7". I tried chmoding it to 777, as some forums suggested, but with no improvement. Please suggest something else